# Quartz Composer : can't see anything in timeline patch

Tags: quartz-composer

I'm very close to have a nervous breakdown ... I hope you can help me

I try to add a timeline patch into a Composition but when I open the Patch Information for edit the Timeline ... there's nothing, only the help text, and if I put it down, a grey empty space ... Do I miss to install a third party soft/add-on ?

It's seems like no one had this problem before ...

In advance thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I uploaded `Timeline` patch into `Animated Clouds`composition and QC successfully showed its Settings window when I pressed:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd>.

So, for me everything works fine.

[image]

[image]

Try using the latest version of QC.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response, but it didn't work for me.

I've find an alternative solution, I open Compositions that need a Timeline on my MacPro, same version of Quartz Composer but ... It show me the timeline. I don't from where come the bug but it's work on my MP (El Capitan) and not on my MBP (Sierra) ...

Comment: I tested it on Mac Pro (Late 2013), in El Capitan 10.11.6, QC version 4.6.2 (153). Graphic Animation template (clouds).

Comment: Yeah for me too it's work on my Mac Pro, it's on my MacBook Pro that it doesn't work. I'll try to upgrade to High Sierra later, may be it'll fix the problem. However thank you very much for responding to me :)